# Automatic Login Via Devise after Password Change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

When i change the password in my app via devise, the user gets logged out.
Is there a quick way so that the same user will get signed in and redirected to some path in devise without doing anything in view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After you update the user record, call sign_in but with the bypass option.

```
 if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
   sign_in(@user, bypass: true)
   redirect_to root_path
 else
   render :edit
 end
```

Comment: Ah, right, then the line above the lines specified should be `authorize @user`